# how to remove all lines from trading view chart with JavaScript?

Tags: tradingview-api

widget.chart().createPositionLine()

how to remove all lines at once?
can anyone help?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAj8k.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
removeLines: function() {
  this.lines.forEach(function(value) {
    value.remove()
  })
  this.lines = [];
}
```

Just make a function while creating new lines, and then empty that array.